# Scan Website Data For Malicious Code & Injections

Tags: malware, scanner

I want to scan a website's complete data, what's most authentic & user friendly tool for that on linux?

Suggest me command line utilites please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this tools:

- Metasploit
- Framework
- NIKTO
- Chkrootkit
- Nessus